# Can an employee be effectivley fired by making their work really bad?

Tags: employment, canada, labor-law

To my understanding

1. An employer is allowed to reduce an employees wage without reason
2. An employer can cancel or reschedule shifts without reason or send an employee home without pay
3. Canada is not employment at will

Despite not being employment at will, can't an employer effectively fire an employee by cancelling all their shifts (or reducing them to something really short)? Can't employer reduce pay to minimum wage?

If it's that easy what's the point of having laws regarding termination?

Comment: What even is constructive dismissal?

Answer (score 4):

### Can they?

**Yes**

### Is it legal?

**No**

This is called [constructive dismissal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dismissal) and it is as illegal as any other dismissal without legal cause.